# Delayed job can't put log in delayed_log.log

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I'm using Deplayed Job. And configured like belows.

confnig/initializations/dj.config

```
Delayed::Worker.destroy_failed_jobs = false
Delayed::Worker.sleep_delay = 60
Delayed::Worker.max_attempts = 0
Delayed::Worker.max_run_time = 10.minutes
Delayed::Worker.read_ahead = 10
Delayed::Worker.default_queue_name = 'default'
Delayed::Worker.delay_jobs = true
Delayed::Worker.raise_signal_exceptions = true
Delayed::Worker.logger = Logger.new(File.join(Rails.root, 'log', 'delayed_job.log'))
```

app/jobs/set_status_job.rb

```
class SetStatusJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  rescue_from(ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound) do |e|
    Delayed::Worker.logger.error "error : #{e}"
    notifier = Slack::Notifier.new "https://hooks.slack.com/services/T0D5CJN2C/aaa/bbbb", channel: "#some-channel", username: "anonymous"
    notifier.ping "Error occured. See this #{e}"
  end

  def perform(queue)
    Delayed::Worker.logger.info 'perform start'
    do_something
    Delayed::Worker.logger.info 'perform end'
  end
```

But unfortunately, whatever I kicked the job, no logs are appeared in delayed_job.log.
Is there any necessary configurations? I'd be happy if anyone know.

Best

Comment: does the dj process have write permission for that log file?

Comment: Oh, thanks! Actually, I'm starting DelayedJob worker in root account. How should I do?

Comment: @razvans Sorry for being late. I changed and add write permission to delayed_job.log. After that, it works. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

The configuration looks ok, the only things that comes to mind is if the user that starts the dj process has write permissions for that file.